# Using a for loop to find a username and password in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to ask the user to enter the username and password and if it is wrong, the programme must repeatedly ask the user to enter the username and password until the correct ones are entered

```
users = {
    'admin': {'password': 'adm1n'},
    'man': {'password': 'thing'},
    'cool': {'password': 'guy'}
}

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter your username: ')

    for username, data in users.items():

        if user_input == username:
            password = input('Enter the password: ')
    
            if password == data['password']:
                print('Welcome')
                break

            else:
                print('The password you have entered is incorrect')
                continue      
        else:
            print('The username does not exist')
            continue

    break
```

The first if statement isn't picking up the users 'man' and 'cool'. It is only picking up 'admin'

If I put in 'admin' and then an incorrect password, 'the username is incorrect shows', It is supposed to show 'The password it incorrect'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, using the "in" statement is really useful. It checks whether something exists within a dictionary rather than your having to directly check each item. I think this code does what you are looking for.

```
users = {
    'admin': {'password': 'adm1n'},
    'man': {'password': 'thing'},
    'cool': {'password': 'guy'}
}

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter your username: ')

    if user_input in users:
        password = input('Enter the password: ')

        if password == users[user_input]['password']:
            print('Welcome')
        else:
            print('The password you have entered is incorrect')
            continue
    else:
        print('The username does not exist')
        continue
    break
```

As to why your code didn't work, I believe your issue is that when you check the first name if it isn't that name (even if is another correct name) your else statement prints that it doesn't exist and continues.